# jhipster - possible to iterate on database schema using JDL Studio?

Tags: jhipster

I'm new to [jhipster](https://www.jhipster.tech/), and have created a JDL file for Entities in my service using [JDL Studio](https://start.jhipster.tech/jdl-studio).

**My goal is to keep iterating on my DB design, using JDL Studio, and then run the service so I can see the Entity screens that jhipster has created. How should I do this?**

I have [reviewed the docs on database updates](https://www.jhipster.tech/development/#database-updates), but I find it doesn't lay out this common development task clearly - wanting to iterate on a DB design. I see suggestions fo using `jhipster entity ...` but does that mean JDL Studio can only be used at the start of development?

My current process I'm hoping will work in some fashion is this:

- Make changes to my entities in JDL Studio
- Download changes to `entities.jdl`
- run `jhipster import-jdl entities.jdl`
- Tell it to overwrite everything - I have no customizations to the code yet in anyway.
- Try and run the service using `./mvnw`

I currently have very little code that is custom so far, and what I have is committed to git, so I can diff/revert changes if need be.

The problem is that I see to get conflicts, or the app breaks and won't compile, around things that seem related to the entities not being updated correctly. I'm perfectly fine with overwriting everything to just get the updated entities, and front end files

I've tried removing `node_modules`, `target`, and `.jhipster/*` files to see if I could cleanly recreate the entities, but it still has conflicts.

Note I'm only using H2 at this point, and don't plan on using liquibase/a real db until I actually release something, so probably months from now. Thanks!

Comment: It should work as expected, JDL import is able to detect modified entities and should not regenerate the ones that did not change unless you removed .jhipster directory.
I think you are removing too many directories.
You should not remove node_modules, it takes too long to download and does not contain any generated code.
You should only remove src and target.
Using JDL is far better than using `jhipster entity` and totally suited to your approach.
Also, you can run the studio locally.

Comment: Why not using Liquibase? It really helps designing your entities incrementally and your UI by loading test data from CSV. Incremental Liquibase changelogs also can help, although they are poorly documented: https://www.jhipster.tech/creating-an-app/#would-you-like-to-use-incremental-liquibase-changelogs

Comment: Thanks for the pointers - I never tried that liquibase option, and will try removing `src` folder instead, as well as running JDL studio locally. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the question comments, the basic process is as I listed in my question. I think there were 2 things that solved my problem

- completely removing the `src` folder, and allowing it to be regenerated
- supplying both my JDL files at once on the command line.

I have 2 JDL files, one for entities, and one for relationships, which I broke out separately while trying to figure out how to best do these updates. I was running them separately as well, which worked fine for the entities JDL file, but wouldn't for the relationships one, as it needed the entities too.

So my solution seems to have been the following:

```
cd my_project
rm -fr src target
jhipster import-jdl entities.jdl relationships.jdl
```

If I found my entities weren't being regenerated, I also deleted the `.jhipster` folder, but not sure if this is required or not

```
rm .jhipster/*
```

Once again - I am completely new to jhipster, so there may be better processes, but this seems to have resolved my issues !